# Refreshing WPF ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have `ComboBox` that lists all enum values using `ObjectDataProvider`. Since enum-values are not always that clear and they need to be localized, I use converter to do that. This all works fine, but when I change the language, I have to somehow update the combobox. How I can do that? ComboBox'es `UpdateLayout()` and `Items.Refresh()` have no effect at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `Refresh` on the `ObjectDataProvider` itself.

Comment: Pavlo is right and be sure that your binding is set to OneWay and not OneTime